# I am using large file upload aws s3 bucket in laravel but i am facing issue

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services

I am using large file upload aws s3 bucket in laravel but i am facing issue "Your proposed upload is smaller than the minimum allowed size" filesize 9.8

```
public function testS3Link()
{
    $link = "http://localhost/instacon-web/public/videoUpload/sample10mb.mp4";
    $time = time();
    // Destination path on S3 bucket
    $s3FilePath = 'instameet/'.$time.".mp4";

    // Initialize S3 client
    $s3 = new S3Client([
        'version' => 'latest',
        'region' => 'ap-south-1', // Change this to your desired AWS region
        'credentials' => [
            'key' => 'AKIAEXAMPLE',
            'secret' => 'examplekey',
        ],
    ]);

    try {
        // Get file size using cURL
        $ch = curl_init($link);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        $fileSize = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD);
        curl_close($ch);

        // Determine the part size
        $partSize = 5 * 1024 * 1024; // 5 MB
        $partNumber = 1;
        
        // If the file size is smaller than the part size, upload it as a single part
        if ($fileSize <= $partSize) {
            $result = $s3->putObject([
                'Bucket' => 'instacon',
                'Key' => $s3FilePath,
                'Body' => fopen($link, 'rb'),
            ]);
            dd($s3FilePath);
        }
        
        // Initiate the multipart upload
        $result = $s3->createMultipartUpload([
            'Bucket' => 'instacon',
            'Key' => $s3FilePath,
        ]);

        // Get the upload ID
        $uploadId = $result['UploadId'];

        // Upload the parts of the file
        $file = fopen($link, 'rb');
        while (!feof($file)) {
            $part = fread($file, $partSize);
            $result = $s3->uploadPart([
                'Bucket' => 'instacon',
                'Key' => $s3FilePath,
                'UploadId' => $uploadId,
                'PartNumber' => $partNumber,
                'Body' => $part,
            ]);
            $parts[] = [
                'PartNumber' => $partNumber,
                'ETag' => $result['ETag'],
            ];
            $partNumber++;
        }
        fclose($file);

        // Complete the multipart upload
        $s3->completeMultipartUpload([
            'Bucket' => 'instacon',
            'Key' => $s3FilePath,
            'UploadId' => $uploadId,
            'MultipartUpload' => [
                'Parts' => $parts,
            ],
        ]);

        dd($s3FilePath);

    } catch (S3Exception $e) {
        // Handle exception
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

the above code i have tried but its not working. Its return error Your proposed upload is smaller than the minimum allowed size. Can you suggest any solution.

Comment: You should immediately revoke your AWS credentials.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please try searching before posting a new question. Searching for your error message turns up other questions about it here already, with answers.  If you already searched and tried those answers, your question should tell us about what you tried.  If you didn't search ... you shouldn't ask a new question.